# ServletRequest NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, jetty

My env Jetty 8.1

```
public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  //this line prints org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request
  System.out.println("class is "+request.getClass().getName());

  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request jettyRequest = (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request)request;
  //request.getServletContext();//this line fails with noSuchMethodError
  jettyRequest.getServletContext(); // this line works

  ...
```

Can anyone explain this....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webapp isn't using Servlet API 3.0.

This will fail if you are using Servlet API 2.5 (for example).

Make sure your webapp's `WEB-INF/web.xml` is set for Servlet API 3.0 and also make sure that any servlet-api jars you might have in `WEB-INF/lib` are removed.

Comment: Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServletContext()

Comment: Why does that function call work if I cast the object as I did in the code above?

Comment: You are casting it to `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request` (an internal class for Jetty) which has had that method for years, as it is a useful method for providing basic servlet support.  However, the servlet-api spec only recently added it to the servlet 3.0 api. (see javadoc link from madth3)